# Adding Jest and Enzyme to React boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to add Jest and Enzyme to my boilerplate react project. I am getting a syntax error on the line

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
```

The full repo is at https://github.com/MattJLeach/react-boilerplate/tree/jest-enzyme as I'm not sure what part of my setup is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: May be an issue with shallow being not found and/or React not found making JS syntax not to compile?

Comment: Looks like it's the latter problem. May want to try updating babel and react, it looks like you're using the older archived packages.
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react
You can see here that this repo is archived
https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env

Comment: The JSX isn't getting compiled before being run by `Jest` so it throws an error on `<`...[this section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react#setup-without-create-react-app) walks through the setup